# WPF Performance using ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary, staticresource

In my WPF application I have a lot of XAML, So I'm little confused in using ResourceDictionary in WPF, Does using it fasted my application or slow it down.

**EX:** Lets say we have the following style for a TextBlock that we want to apply it to a lot of TextBlock's in my application:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" x:Key="MainText">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="20" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Droid Arabic Kufi" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF383838"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
</Style>
```

What is the best approach for my application performance, Declared the style in ResourceDictionary like above and using it as following:

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource MainText}" Text="Hello"/>
```

Or repeat the style (FontWeight, FontFamily, Foreground ... ) in each one?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There shouldn't be a noticeable performance difference. It's only about convenience (not having to manually reapply all the properties on every control)

Comment: But if you really want to know, setting all the properties manually is likely slightly faster at startup (because you remove one indirection level). Once the control has been loaded, there should be no more difference (since the values of all properties have been resolved)

Comment: There won't be any noticable difference in performance (if there is any at all). However, setting properties once in a Style and using that Style for many controls results in significantly better application design.

Comment: Actually, resource dictionary can be your best friend, as, once used only as application resources, will give you both the best performance an memory consumption, but you need to use ResourceKey to get that. But if you have numerous dictionaries, you can end up with slowness and larger memory footprint.

Comment: @AlexSeleznyov Please can you provide me with more details about ResourceKey? Thanks in advance

Comment: MSDN has a pretty extensive description here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/componentresourcekey-markup-extension . Let me know if that link is not providing you with enough information, and I'll try to make an example a bit later.

Comment: Thanks @AlexSeleznyov

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a performance difference for using it either way like that.  Performance strains on ResourceDictionaries are used only when the view is Initialized.  The reason for the strain is because it looks first inward and then outward for the resource until it finds the first one of that key.  So if the resource is in the control then it's found faster, then it searches the parent of that control and so on to the Window (usually MainWindow), and finally the Application. (Meaning the closer to the control the resource is the faster it's found and used.. but that speed is NOT an issue. It only really becomes an issue in apps that have a LOT of shared ResourceDictionary's at the App level.)

There are very efficient and clever ways to get around this constraint but it's not an issue unless your views are rendering slowly based solely on this.  Once the view is rendered it has a direct reference to the source and there are no more checks.  Now if the control is created, while the view is already rendered, such as a Template in an ItemsControl, and the Templates are referencing those resources then the list may show the penalty upon updating and other things of that nature.

To the point... Don't worry about performance unless the ResourceDictionary's are at the App level AND you have a lot of them.

Comment: I'd say the exact opposite holds true. You should **avoid** `ResourceDictionary` on view level - at all cost. [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/optimizing-performance-application-resources)

Comment: @l33t I do agree the App and Window are the best managed places to place the resource, unless it's used in a ControlTemplate or something more specific like so.  However; there is a discussion about performance and regardless of whether the App or Window level are the best options they are among the last to be search for resources.  In most situations this isn't a problem but there are times when resource lookup can be a slight bottle neck depending on how you layout your views.  :/

Comment: If resource is on view level, it will be loaded when the view loads. That, itself, could easily kill performance. Especially if the resource dictionary is large. I guess you have to weigh this cost and the cost of resource lookup.